# Bash script exit on error (set -e) closes putty SSH session

Tags: ssh, putty

I'm using set -e to force my script to exit whenever an error occurs running a command.
However this has the side effect of closing my putty terminal window that I am using to connect via SSH to the host.

How do I stop the terminal from closing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How are you running the script?  The circumstances of a subprocess's exit shouldn't affect the shell that ran it... unless you're sourcing the script into your running shell.

For example...

```
./my-script.sh # this should terminate and leave your shell intact
. my-script.sh # this might terminate and take your shell with it
```

A 'nix shell is a running process of some shell interpreter (e.g., `bash`, `ksh`, `csh`).  "source"ing a script (which you can do in `bash` with the command `source` or its alias `.`) tells that interpreter to open the indicated file and process its contents.  In effect, the script becomes a shortcut for entering commands interactively.  Functions defined, variables set, and (in your case) `exit`s processed take effect in the original shell.

`./my-script.sh` is a simple file path. `./` refers to the current directory and `my-script.sh` to a script within that directory.  When the file is marked as executable, the file will be executed.  In the case of a script, this means launching a new interpreter process (as defined by the `#!` line at the top of the script, or `/bin/sh` by default) and using it to interpret the script.  Functions defined, variables set, and `exit`s processed are confined to that new interpreter process.

Comment: You are right I am using ". my-script". Can you explain the difference please?

Comment: To put it inelegantly, "./my-script.sh" means "run the program ./my-script.sh" as a new process. ". my-script.sh" means "make this script part of my current process".

Comment: I edited my answer to add further explanation, as requested.

Comment: Man, I cannot believe all this time I was reconnecting, logging in, setting up environment and executing because of this minor quirk! lol!